# Adding Multi select optionset in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am looking to add a Multi select optionset in a CRM 2016 entity form. As Multi select optionset is not an available out of box field type (we have optionset, two options available).

How to create this particular field type?

(P.S. - I have tried some Javascript to enable optionset as multi select but having troubles here. Is there a way other than this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to DotNetPro answer, would like to mention next [Dynamics CRM 365 (online) update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/new-in-july-2017-update-for-developers#new-attribute-type-multi-select-option-set) @ July 2017 will have new datatype: [Multi-select optionset](http://www.powerobjects.com/2017/07/19/dynamics-365-july-2017-update-multi-select-option-sets/)

[image]

For now, N:N relationship will give you supported customizations.

If you are using [Matre blog](https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.com/2015/02/convert-option-set-to-multi-select.html?_sm_au_=iVVMqDZLfqt645Nq&m=1), consider Shaik's reply on this [thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/224750).

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box support for multi-select pick lists in Dynamics CRM but since the latest UI improvements in CRM2016 you can use a standard N:N Relationship with form sub-grid to get a most respectable multiple selection form field.

You can try some JavaScript that will convert the `OptionSet` to `Multi-select` but these will be **`un-supported`** customization's and the functionality could break in future upgrades.

**Sample Code on the 2nd Url below:**

```
//Coverts option list to checkbox list.
    function ConvertDropDownToCheckBoxList() {
        var dropdownOptions = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_makeyear").getOptions();
        var selectedValue = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_selectedyears").getValue();

        $(dropdownOptions).each(function (i, e) {
            var rText = $(this)[0].text;
            var rvalue = $(this)[0].value;
            var isChecked = false;
            if (rText != '') {
                if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue.indexOf(rvalue) != -1)
                    isChecked = true;

/* Remove spaces before input, label word and end tags of input & label*/
                var checkbox = "< input type='checkbox' name='r'/ >< label> " + rText + "</ label>"
```

[Simple multi-select lists in CRM 2013
There is no out of the box support for multi-selec](https://crmtipoftheday.com/47/simple-multi-select-lists-in-crm-2013/)

[Convert Option set to multi select Checkbox list](https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.com/2015/02/convert-option-set-to-multi-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also consider using editable sub-grids to create child records which simply have the option set on.